# How to create live preview of websites in form of thumbnails?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I would like to know if there is a way to make a live preview of websites from URL in form of a thumbnail? Idea is that user enters the URL on his account and he gets a live preview of a website in form of thumbnail, just like google chrome has shortcuts of recently visited websites, but should work in any browser. I tried with iframe but I got "website inside website", could click on links, menus and everything. It was really weird, ha.
Thanks ;)

Comment: which is it thumbnail or live? Screenshots can easily be done using wkhtmltopdf or some other tool, and a live site though an iframe will have clickable links.. but you could place a div that covers the iframe to stop obvious clicking, though the site will not scale like an image and will have all its responsiveness..

Comment: You might be able to use HTML5, JavaScript and a canvas to create the live thumbnail.  Take a look at this related post: [Question 4912092]

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots

Answer (score 1):

You could iframe the site, decorate it with a border, use CSS transformations to shrink it to a "thumbnail", then use CSS to ensure that mouse interactions are ignored.

```css
#frame {
  border: 10px solid blue;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-200px,-200px) scale(.2, .2);
  -moz-transform: translate(-200px,-200px) scale(.2, .2);
  -o-transform: translate(-200px,-200px) scale(.2, .2);
  -ms-transform: translate(-200px,-200px) scale(.2, .2);
  transform: translate(-200px,-200px) scale(.2, .2);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<iframe id="frame" src="https://stackoverflow.com" scrolling="no"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the embed tag  with a src and type of text/html 
example

```html
<embed src="+page+" type="text/html"/>
```

Comment: Not every site will have CORS enabled with X-Frame-Options set `<embed src="https://google.com" type="text/html"/>`...

Comment: then he can nest it in an Object tag and set the data property to the same url